# Why when I set an OWNER RIGHTS ACE, does it get inheritance flags that I didn't set?

Tags: c++, windows, process, permissions, atl

I'm trying to tighten the security on a Windows process, by overriding the process owners ability to further alter the DACL on the process.

Having created the process with `CreateProcessAsUser()`

I then proceed to get the existing DACL from it like so:

```
CDacl procDacl;
if (AtlGetDacl(hProcess, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, &procDacl))
{
   //..
}
```

After this, I construct an OWNER RIGHTS ACE and add it to the DACL so that the owner only has read access to the permissions (this removes the default WRITE_DAC access):

```
PSID OwnerRightsSid;
if (ConvertStringSidToSid(OWNER_RIGHTS_SID_STRING, &OwnerRightsSid))
{
    CSid sidOwnerRights(*static_cast<SID*>(OwnerRightsSid));
    LocalFree(OwnerRightsSid);
    procDacl.AddAllowedAce(sidOwnerRights, READ_CONTROL);
}
```

Before setting the DACL back on the process.

```
AtlSetDacl(hProcess, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, procDacl, PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION);
```

If I use `AtlGetDacl()` at this point I can enumerate the ACEs and see that all of them have 0 flags.  However, looking at the process in WinDBG I see the owner rights SID has gained flag 0x8 (INHERIT_ONLY_ACE) which means it doesn't actually apply to the process its self.  What's weird is that:

1. All the other ACEs I've added in the same way have flag 0 as expected.
2. But if I use process explorer or process hacker, they're able to set the OWNER RIGHTS sid without this inheritance problem... (Note the owner rights sid: S-1-3-4)

Here's my ACEs in WinDBG:

```
0: kd> !sd (0xffff8903`70d9d5e7 & 0xffffffff`fffffff0)
->Revision: 0x1
->Sbz1    : 0x0
->Control : 0x8014
            SE_DACL_PRESENT
            SE_SACL_PRESENT
            SE_SELF_RELATIVE
->Owner   : S-1-5-21-2264418099-4034413657-3176887289-1001
->Group   : S-1-5-21-2264418099-4034413657-3176887289-513
->Dacl    : 
->Dacl    : ->AclRevision: 0x2
->Dacl    : ->Sbz1       : 0x0
->Dacl    : ->AclSize    : 0x64
->Dacl    : ->AceCount   : 0x4
->Dacl    : ->Sbz2       : 0x0
->Dacl    : ->Ace[0]: ->AceType: ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE
->Dacl    : ->Ace[0]: ->AceFlags: 0x0
->Dacl    : ->Ace[0]: ->AceSize: 0x14
->Dacl    : ->Ace[0]: ->Mask : 0x001fffff
->Dacl    : ->Ace[0]: ->SID: S-1-5-18

->Dacl    : ->Ace[1]: ->AceType: ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE
->Dacl    : ->Ace[1]: ->AceFlags: 0x0
->Dacl    : ->Ace[1]: ->AceSize: 0x18
->Dacl    : ->Ace[1]: ->Mask : 0x001fffff
->Dacl    : ->Ace[1]: ->SID: S-1-5-32-544

->Dacl    : ->Ace[2]: ->AceType: ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE
->Dacl    : ->Ace[2]: ->AceFlags: 0x0
->Dacl    : ->Ace[2]: ->AceSize: 0x1c
->Dacl    : ->Ace[2]: ->Mask : 0x00120410
->Dacl    : ->Ace[2]: ->SID: S-1-5-5-0-165627

->Dacl    : ->Ace[3]: ->AceType: ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE
->Dacl    : ->Ace[3]: ->AceFlags: 0x8
->Dacl    : ->Ace[3]:             INHERIT_ONLY_ACE
->Dacl    : ->Ace[3]: ->AceSize: 0x14
->Dacl    : ->Ace[3]: ->Mask : 0x00020000
->Dacl    : ->Ace[3]: ->SID: S-1-3-4

->Sacl    : 
->Sacl    : ->AclRevision: 0x2
->Sacl    : ->Sbz1       : 0x0
->Sacl    : ->AclSize    : 0x1c
->Sacl    : ->AceCount   : 0x1
->Sacl    : ->Sbz2       : 0x0
->Sacl    : ->Ace[0]: ->AceType: SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_ACE_TYPE
->Sacl    : ->Ace[0]: ->AceFlags: 0x0
->Sacl    : ->Ace[0]: ->AceSize: 0x14
->Sacl    : ->Ace[0]: ->Mask : 0x00000003
->Sacl    : ->Ace[0]: ->SID: S-1-16-8192
```

I've already tried looking at the process hacker source code, and I can't see that they're doing anything differently (Except that they seem to be using SetObjectInfo() rather than the ATL wrapper functions).  Does anyone have a good understanding how how these inheritance flags work?  And why my ACE seems to have been altered from the flags I set?

Comment: It works fine for me with WinAPI, `GetSecurityInfo`, `AddAccessAllowedAceEx`, and finally `SetSecurityInfo(hProcess, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, pDacl, NULL)`. Maybe it's an ATL issue.

Comment: @ErykSun - Thanks for trying it!  How did you check it worked?  Did you check in WinDBG because I notice that in process explorer you can't see the INHERIT_ONLY_ACE.

Comment: Yes, I checked in a kernel debugger.

Comment: @ErykSun - And you tried with S-1-3-4 ?  It does seem to work with other SIDs which is what makes this so weird..

Comment: That would be the subject of the question, so, yes, I used "OWNER RIGHTS" (S-1-3-4).

Comment: Ok, sorry, just making sure.  The ATL appears to be a pretty thin wrapper around those functions so maybe I have some corruption creeping in somewhere.  Thanks again.

Comment: no, it not get this flag if you not set it

Comment: @ErykSun - Pretty weird day of debugging.  Following your lead I wrote a small app with the ATL to launch a process and manipulate ACLs.  This worked just fine as yours did.  In our product though, it seems as though the process is in an interesting state.  Only closing the process and reopening it before applying this particular ACL worked as expected and then I saw the ACL look good in the kernel debugger.  I traced this back to the application of a custom token applied with ZwSetInformationProcess().  The process had to be closed/reopened after this had taken place.  Pretty weird fix..